# turning a synchronous function into asynchronous function

Tags: node.js

I have a for loop which does many iterations .I would like to put that piece of code in a custom async function as it is blocking.Is there anyway I can write a function so it will call a callback once the loop iteration is over?.

Comment: If you don't have any non-blocking operations, async will not help you at all.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: i would change my look for a recursive function and and always defer the next execution to the next tick

Comment: you may have a look at async library -https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: As SLaks stated this approach is not really useful. If you have a very work intensive Loop there, you could maybe think about extracting it into another NodeJS-Process and call it with the child-process lib.

Comment: That sounds good, but how do I fork another process?..isnt node single threaded?

Comment: like Charminbear said, check out the `child-process` node lib. your invoked program doesn't have to be a node program -- it could be Perl, Python, whatever. Whatever it is, the child proc then becomes a non-blocked i/o task just like db and filesystem ops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asynchronous-function-inside-a-loop paradigm. This ensures that the asynchronous functions get called with the correct value of the index variable.

```
    var total = someObject.list.length;
    var count = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < total; i++){
    (function(foo){
    myobj.get(someObject.list[foo], function(err, response) {
        do_something(foo);
        count++;
        if (count > total - 1) done();
    });
    }(i)); //To immediately invoke the function passing 'i' as parameter
    }


    function done() {
    console.log('All data loaded');
    }
```